# Counter of a set of barcodes using Array Formula or Pivot Table

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I have a sheet with barcodes of a bunch of things as such -

```
Col A   Col B ...
ABC12   EF34
EF34    ABC12
ABC12
GH56
```

And I want in another sheet a counter of the unique set of those with counts, such as-

```
Barcode  Count 

ABC12      3    
EF34       2     
GH56       1
```

What is the simplest way to implement this counter?

I was able to obtain all the unique values using:

```
=unique(query({all!A:A;all!B:B;all!C:C;all!D:D;all!E:E;all!F:F;all!G:G;all!H:H;all!I:I;all!J:J;all!K:K;all!L:L;all!M:M;all!N:N;all!O:O;all!P:P;all!Q:Q;all!R:R;all!S:S;all!T:T;all!U:U;all!V:V;all!W:W;all!X:X;all!Y:Y;all!Z:Z}, "where Col1 <>''"))
```

And then obtain the counts using:

```
=COUNTIF(all!$A$2:$Z$1000,$B28)
```

For each of the unique values, captured in the column.

But my solution feels hacky, and I feel like, set counter operation of array formula can be implemented possibly simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

`=query(flatten({A2:C}),"select Col1,count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label Col1 'Barcode',count(Col1) 'Count' ",0)`

[image]

Comment: Thanks!

I didn't realize that you could literally write a SQL query on Sheets! Guess I will have to dif into that, to make everything simple.

Nor did I know the flatten function.

Very helpful!